# Submit html form info to other website in real time

Tags: php, html, node.js, forms, backend

I was wondering if there was a way to take information inputted on an html form and input that info on a form on a different website and display a response in real time.

So like I submit info on my form, the program uses that info and tries it on the other form and based on the other forms response it displays a response on my form.

Comment: Yes there are ways to do this...

Comment: Ok, but how to do this lol...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by using to store one information into cookie and then to read that cookie data from another website.

It is language specific task but you can handle it with PHP very easy.

Comment: hmm. I have searched some more and am trying php cURL. do you think this would work?